# Github Repository Clone

Tags: github

My Github Repository is public and I am working on it. I see everyday 12-14 unique cloners in my repository . Is it safe for me that people are cloning my Github repository?

I added MIT license but still visitors are able to clone my repository.

Comment: It is safe for you if people are cloning a public repository. It might a little disconcerting if you don't expect that ... apparently your repository is very popular, so that is good news (I hope).

Comment: If you don't want people to clone your repository, why do you make it public? Why would cloning be unsafe, for what definition of "unsafe"? The license defines what people are legally allowed to do, not technically.